# How can I describe preparing before travel?

Tags: conversation

If I am preparing before my travel and I pack my things, how can I better describe this process in conversational speech, "packing up one's things" or "I pack up one's things"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're "packing for the trip", "packing your bags", "packing your things", or "getting packed":

> I'd better go pack for the trip.
>
> I'd better go pack my bags.
>
> I'd better go pack my things.
>
> I'd better go and get packed.

All of those are equivalent, and common in conversational speech.

Comment: But not "I pack up one's things", or "I'm packing one's things"!